# In a web application can I suppress a JS message which popup in client side browser?

Tags: c#, api, internet-explorer, hook, suppress

I'm working on a web application, which in some times JS messages and alerts popup, I want to suppress this messages and alerts from poping up, How can I do that if I don't know when or where this message pop up from using c# code?!

in other words, how I can take control on the IE window(client side) in which this message popup and how to simulate a click event on the "OK" button in that message.

Hope you got it !

please help me because I'm runnig out of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually overide the standard alert function with a custom one in javascript

```
window.alert = function(message) {
   // process or swallow the message
}
```

[See this](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) for more details